# Hadoop Pig Output Directory not set

Tags: hadoop, bigdata, apache-pig

I'm writing my own Pig Store class where I don't want to store in a file, I'm planning to send it to some 3rd party data store (short of  API calls).

note: I'm running it on Cloudera's VirtualBox image.

I have written my java classes (listed below) and created mystore.jar which I'm using in below id.pig script:

```
store B INTO 'mylocation' USING MyStore('mynewlocation')
```

while running this script with pig, I see below errors:
    ERROR 6000:
    Output location validation failed for: 'file://home/cloudera/test/id.out More info to follow:
    Output directory not set.

```
or.apache.pig.impl.plan.VisitorException: ERROR 6000:
at or.apache.pig.newplan.logical.rules.InputOutputFileValidator$InputOutputFileValidator.visit(InputOutputFileValidator.java:95)
```

Please help!

-------------------- MyStore.java ----------------------

```
public class MyStore extends StoreFunc {
    protected RecordWriter writer = null;
    private String location = null;


    public MyStore () {
        location= null;
    }

    public MyStore (String location) {
        this.location= location;
    }

    @Override
    public OutputFormat getOutputFormat() throws IOException {
        return new MyStoreOutputFormat(location);
    }

    @Override
    public void prepareToWrite(RecordWriter writer) throws IOException {
        this.writer = writer;
    }

    @Override
    public void putNext(Tuple tuple) throws IOException {
        //write tuple to location

        try {
            writer.write(null, tuple.toString());
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {          
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setStoreLocation(String location, Job job) throws IOException {
        if(location!= null)
            this.location= location;
    }

}
```

-------------------- MyStoreOutputFormat.java ----------------------

```
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.WritableComparable;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.RecordWriter;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskAttemptContext;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;
import org.apache.pig.data.Tuple;

public class MyStoreOutputFormat extends
        TextOutputFormat<WritableComparable, Tuple> {
    private String location = null;

    public MyStoreOutputFormat(String location) {

        this.location = location;
    }

    @Override
    public RecordWriter<WritableComparable, Tuple> getRecordWriter(
            TaskAttemptContext job) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        Configuration conf = job.getConfiguration();

        String extension = location;
        Path file = getDefaultWorkFile(job, extension);     
        FileSystem fs = file.getFileSystem(conf);

        FSDataOutputStream fileOut = fs.create(file, false);

        return new MyStoreRecordWriter(fileOut);
    }

    protected static class MyStoreRecordWriter extends
            RecordWriter<WritableComparable, Tuple> {

        DataOutputStream out = null;

        public MyStoreRecordWriter(DataOutputStream out) {
            this.out = out;
        }

        @Override
        public void close(TaskAttemptContext taskContext) throws IOException,
                InterruptedException {
            // close the location
        }

        @Override
        public void write(WritableComparable key, Tuple value)
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {

            // write the data to location
            if (out != null) {
                out.writeChars(value.toString()); // will be calling API later. let me first dump to the location!
            }
        }

    }
}
```

am I missing anything here?

Comment: please help. I need it urgently. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, i think you should be using the Job configuration to store the location value, rather than a instance variable

Your assignment to a local variable 'location' in the setStoreLocation method is called when planning the job, but the getOutputFormat call may not be made until the execution phase, by which time the location variable may no longer set (a new instance of your class may have been created).

If you look at the source for `PigStorage.setStoreLocation`, you should notice that they store the location in the Job configuration (2nd line):

```
@Override
public void setStoreLocation(String location, Job job) throws IOException {
    job.getConfiguration().set("mapred.textoutputformat.separator", "");
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(location));

    if( "true".equals( job.getConfiguration().get( "output.compression.enabled" ) ) ) {
        FileOutputFormat.setCompressOutput( job, true );
        String codec = job.getConfiguration().get( "output.compression.codec" );
        try {
            FileOutputFormat.setOutputCompressorClass( job,  (Class<? extends CompressionCodec>) Class.forName( codec ) );
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Class not found: " + codec );
        }
    } else {
        // This makes it so that storing to a directory ending with ".gz" or ".bz2" works.
        setCompression(new Path(location), job);
    }
}
```

So i think you should store the location in a job variable:

```
@Override
public void setStoreLocation(String location, Job job) throws IOException {
    if(location!= null)
        job.getConfiguration().set("mylocation", location);
}
```

Which your custom output format can then extract in the createRecordReader method:

```
@Override
public RecordWriter<WritableComparable, Tuple> getRecordWriter(
        TaskAttemptContext job) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    Configuration conf = job.getConfiguration();

    String extension = conf.get("mylocation");
    Path file = getDefaultWorkFile(job, extension);     
    FileSystem fs = file.getFileSystem(conf);

    FSDataOutputStream fileOut = fs.create(file, false);

    return new MyStoreRecordWriter(fileOut);
}
```

Finally (and probably the actual cause of the error you're seeing), your output format extends TextOutputFormat, and you use the `getDefaultWorkFile` method in your record writer - this method needs to know where you are outputting the file to in HDFS, and you haven't called `FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(location));` in your setStoreLocation method (see the PigStorage.setStoreLocation method i previously pasted). So the error is because it doesn't know where to create the default work file.

Comment: thanks Chris. I was missing "FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(location));" call. changed my code according to ur inputs.